# Getting error why scraping data from Twitter using the API

Tags: python, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I was trying to use the function below functions for Twitter data scraping.

```
tweets_copy = []
for tweet in tqdm(tweets):
    tweets_copy.append(tweet)
```

I am getting the error below:

> TweepError: Failed to send request: Only unicode objects are escapable. Got None of type <class 'NoneType'>.

I will appreciate any help.

I tried this:

```
tweets_copy = []
for tweet in tqdm(tweets):
    tweets_copy.append(tweet)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to check for `None`, which the library can't handle

```
tweets_copy = []
for tweet in tqdm(tweets):
    if tweet:
        tweets_copy.append(tweet)
```

Or, alternatively, in [comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) style:

```
tweets_copy = [t for t in tqdm(tweets) if t]
```

Comment: Thanks for helping.  I have been able to solve the problem it is has to do with the way i parse the Twitter API key in.